# converting current datetime to different format

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

How can I convert the DateTime.now()  to the following format in C#.

```
2020-05-28T00:00:02Z
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");` based on the second example you've provided.

Comment: What language is this? You've tagged it as C#, but the code isn't. `system.now()`, `System.debug(...)` and `formatGmt(...)` are not .NET methods.

Comment: And C# uses `"` to start and end a string, not `'`.

Comment: Looks like Salesforce Apex :)

Comment: I want to convert it in C#

Answer (score -1):

It will work as you specify
`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSZ")`

Comment: Did you test this before posting?

Comment: Aside from anything else, using `DateTime.Now` but formatting it as a string ending in Z (which indicates UTC) will give incorrect data. If the OP really wants the current instant in time, as UTC, they should use `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: any help with this question